# Следует ли удалять старые товары для ускорения магазина?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть много старых товаров на сайте, которых уже нет и не будет. На сайте всего товаров порядка 2200. Сайт достаточно посещаемый, существует более 2х лет, но уже ощутимо тормозит. Поможет ли удаление неактуальных позиций?

Comment: Я сомневаюсь что сильно поможет. Добавьте кеш используйте Black Fire, чтобы найти проблему в производительности

Comment: 2200 - это ни о чём для WC. Проблема в чём-то другом.

Comment: @WPPunk и да, для пользователя с таким ником совет вдвойне точный ))

Comment: @KAGGDesign я тоже угарнул над этим :D

Comment: Автора вопроса, вы не обижайтесь, мы дружески шутим, имея ввиду весьма полезный сервис blackfire.io

Comment: да, я слышал о нём)